# (excel VBA): copy remaining rows of recordset to a second sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code which will copy the results of a stored procedure to an excel worksheet:

```
Set rs = cmd.Execute(, , adCmdStoredProc)
Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).CopyFromRecordset rs
```

There are cases where the result from executing the store procedure exceeds the maximum limit of rows an excel sheet can have (1048576 rows).

So for cases like this, how can I improve the code so that the remaining rows after row 1048576 will be copied to a second worksheet?
(example: The recordset returns 1100000 rows (51424 rows exceeded limit, how can I put the remaining rows to the next worksheet?)

Thanks!

Comment: Make a new stored procedure that takes a `@page` parameter, and paginate your results. Curious what use is 1.1 million rows in Excel though. Consider further aggregating the data and giving Excel only what it actually needs.

Comment: Also, if you do `cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc` before you execute it, `Set rs = cmd.Execute` is all you need on that line.

Answer (score 0):

Just move to another worksheet and run `CopyFromRecordset` again to copy the remaining rows, like this fragment:

```
' A quick Cartesian product to get a recordset with over 1 million rows
' The two columns referenced are called A and B; both have over 1024 rows
' cn is the connection and rs is the recordset
rs.Open "SELECT [Sheet1$].[A], [Sheet2$].[B] FROM [Sheet1$], [Sheet2$];", cn

' Output the field names and the results
Dim fld As Object
Dim i As Integer

' Output the first 1048575 rows
With Worksheets("Sheet3")
    .UsedRange.ClearContents

    i = 0
    For Each fld In rs.Fields
        i = i + 1
        .Cells(1, i).Value = fld.Name
    Next fld

    .Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
End With

' Output any remaining rows
If Not rs.EOF Then
    With Worksheets("Sheet4")
        .UsedRange.ClearContents

        i = 0
        For Each fld In rs.Fields
            i = i + 1
            .Cells(1, i).Value = fld.Name
        Next fld

        .Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With
End If
```

You could extend this to even more sheets by looping and checking `rs.EOF` each time. This was more of an issue back in Excel 97-2003 when you only had 65K rows on a sheet